# cors error when using onRequest cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

This is my function

```
export const testFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const text = req.body.text;
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.send({text: text});
});
```

i've tried using `const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});`

I keep getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVhYr.png) as a response. Does anyone know why?

Comment: *I keep getting a cors error as a response.* Please edit your question and add the error message in question.

Comment: I have edited the answer below. Please try and check if you are able to get the output without error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider importing like this,

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
```

And try running the below function using `firebase deploy –only functions` :

```
const functions= require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 cors(req, res, () => {
   const text = req.body.name;
   res.send({text:text});
 });
});
```

And then send request using :

```
curl -X POST "https:/region-projectID.cloudfunctions.net/function-name" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"name":"Keyboard Cat"}'
```

The output I am getting in the console is :
[image]

And when I click on the Cloud Function URL endpoint, my output is an empty {}.

[image]

If you try `res.send(“Hello World”)` in place of `res.send({text:text})`, you will get the output in the browser as `Hello World` but since our Cloud Function performs some contrived operation using data passed in the request body.This could result in an error at run time if the property name is null or undefined.
And indeed, if we deploy this new function and then attempt to call it from our web app without updating our request we do get an error. However, it might not be the error you’d expect.

It’d be easy to assume that we somehow misconfigured our CORS policy. Infact swapping `cors()` to `cors({ origin: '*'})` to `cors({ origin: true})` all to no avail. Only when we view the logs for our Cloud Function do we get a useful error message.

So try sending a POST request with the –data flag, or if you are using Postman, send the data and the parameters. Then only you would be able to have an output, if you still see the CORS error, check if your function is handled well or your nested request body attribute is not undefined/null. Sometimes CORS errors are not  always CORS!

Comment: I've tried that and nothing changed.

Comment: @DanielSpiers Can you check if the above answer works for you?